# Is this circuit for attaching an amplifier to crystal radio going to work?

Tags: amplifier, radio, crystal-set

This is a circuit I created and I was wondering if its going to work, by the way I am new to electronics so if you see any obvious mistakes please let me know.

[image]

Comment: You need a diode detector adding into your circuit. The collector resistor doesn't appear to have any use and, where you have the speaker you won't get voltage amplification. Just a few thoughts.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for response

Comment: Current flows best round loops known as circuits. You only have a single connection from the tuned circuit to your amplifier. To make it into a circuit you need to connect the negative rail from the battery back to the earth on the tuned circuit. To get voltage amplification connect the speaker to the collector of the transistor via a DC blocking capacitor. Google "common emitter amplifier design" to see how to choose the resistor values for your amplifier.

Comment: @Mr.Ananas - Hi, Although we welcome beginners here, please understand that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. The etiquette here differs from typical forums - see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules. || You have asked several related questions in a short time (which has been flagged to us by other site members). This can mean someone is relying on answers from here, without doing their own research between questions. We expect people to [show their research](/help/how-to-ask) and avoid open-ended discussion. || You can ask more open-ended questions in [chat]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say you need a detector. The 'crystal' in 'crystal radio' is the detector, so you've left out an important part. Originally this was a crystal of [galena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galena), later versions used [germanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanium) diodes but those are getting to be harder to find. A silicon diode will have poor sensitive because of it's higher junction voltage (0.7 V vs. 0.3 V), this can be improved by adding a small bias voltage but they're not the best choice. Schottky diodes can have a low voltage drop (around 0.2 V) so these are sometimes used. I would recommend doing a search for *crystal radio detector diodes* and reading some articles about them to get a better idea of what you need. There are plenty of websites devoted to crystal radio design.

Also the amplifier is set up as common collector, so it will not have voltage gain, and there will be a DC bias on the speaker that will displace the voice coil so it is not centered in it’s movement. You can fix the bias problem by capacitively coupling the speaker but it still won’t be very good. You might look at using something like an [LM386](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) amplifier IC.